# Referring external dll in the SSIS package deployed in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

I have created SSIS packages on VS 2010 shell and I am able to successfully deploy my packages to SQL Server and referring external .NET dll in the data flow script component to perform some activities.

May i know steps to deploy the .NET dll in the database server to execute the DTSX deployed in SQL server ?

Answer (score 0):

You won't deploy the external DLLs into SQL Server to support your SSIS packages. Instead, you're going to need to sign the assemblies and then deploy them into the Global Assembly Cache - GAC.

Comment: thanks Billinkc for your response.... i will try this option by signing the dll and deploy it to the GAC and execute the package from SQL server.